# How to get top logprobs dictionary from OpenAI with HuggingFace models?

Tags: python, nlp, large-language-model

I am trying to use a HuggingFace model (Bloom) to generate text and evaluate the token probabilities of all possible completions.
I want to generate something alongside OpenAI's 'top logprobs' condition, so we get a dictionary such as:
{
" No": -1.2539079,
" Yes": -0.36010918,
" No": -5.115541,
" High": -6.792852,
" Maybe": -6.834635
}
This is the code I have now:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch
torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("bigscience/bloom-560m", use_cache=True)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bigscience/bloom-560m")
input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors = "pt").to(0)
outputs = model.generate(**input_ids, max_length = 450, return_dict_in_generate = True, output_scores = True)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0][0], truncate_before_pattern=[r"\n\n^#", "^'''", "\n\n\n"]))
```

I am not sure how to approach this -- I heard setting "return_dict_in_generate" and "output_scores=True" could do this, but I still do not know how to access those scores.